# How to inspect the java memory except heap and perm gen

Tags: java, jmxtrans

I run jmxtrans with option: -Xms16m -Xmx16m -XX:MaxPermSize=32m, however from the os view, the process taken about 190m memory, I use jstat the usage of new, old and perm are under my max memory settings, so what objects taken the extra memory? more than 150m

ps aux output:

```
ps aux | grep jmxtrans
root        187  0.4  0.0 5987252 196492 ?      Sl   Jul07  17:15 
/usr/java/jdk7/bin/java -server -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms16m -Xmx16m -XX:MaxPermSize=32m -Djmxtrans.log.level=info -Djmxtrans.log.dir=. -Dhost=5e7d319eaae7 -DjmxPort=59100 -DserviceName=maxwell -DserviceVersion=v1.0 -jar lib/jmxtrans-all.jar -e -f /jmxtrans/jmxtrans.json -s 60 -c false
```

jstat output:

```
# jstat -gc 187 1 1
S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
512.0  512.0  288.0   0.0    4096.0   1043.8   11264.0     5822.7   26112.0 25959.7   2644   26.102  67     24.894   50.996
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-Heap Memory and something else, it's quite normal jvm heap memory not match the res memory. see [JVM Memory Structure](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/kb/sizes.jsp)